# No configuration for database at org.telosys.tools.commons.dbcfg.DbConnectionManager.getConnection (line 76)

Tags: mysql, entities, sts, telosys

I am trying to get all `entities` (in STS) from an existing `MYSQL` `data model`.
I have been researching many tools, and finally decided to use '`telosys`'.
This marketplace tool allows you to easily obtain the entities, it is only necessary to configure the `url`, `username`, `password`... and the rest is filled in automatically.

[image: Config telosys info]
[image: Meta-data info]

I have the problem when creating the model, which gives me a `Telosys` error.

Cannot create `database` model

[image: Error message]

I don't understand very well what you mean, it says that there is no configuration for the `database`, but I have filled in everything necessary.
I can't find information about this error either by `SO` or on the web.

Thank you very much for any kind of help.

I know there is a `g9-tool` to do this kind of automatic `database` to `entity` conversions, but my data model has a lot of tables, and `g9` allows you free use of up to 12 tables.

Comment: Strange, it works fine for me.
This error message means that your database is not realy defined in the file.
You can try to open the file "databases.dbcfg" with a text editor to see the real content of the file (right-click : "Open With" --> "Text editor")
Are you sure the file is saved in the workspace?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a '*' before 'databases.cfg' in the tab title.

So I'm guessing your file hasn't been saved yet and therefore the generator can't found your new database configuration.

Make sure to save the file 'databases.cfg' (with Ctrl-S or with the menu: "File-Save") before launching "Create model" or "Update model"